# Watching the Output of a Function in a Controller From Directive with Ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having difficulty getting a custom directive to watch the result of a function bound to the scope in the controller.

This is the html. I am passing the key of the `ng-repeat` to the function in the controller to decide whether this element is active or not.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myArray" my-custom-directive element-is-active="elementIsActive(key)">
</div>
```

This is the relevant code in the controller. Based on user's input, this function returns true or false, indicating whether the element is selected or not.

```
$scope.elementIsActive = function (key) {
    if(key===$scope.selectedElement) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If this element is active, I want to use the functionality in the custom directive. This is the custom directive:

```
myAngularModule.directive('myCustomDirective', function (){

    function link (scope, element, attrs)  {

        scope.$watch(scope.active(), function (){
            console.log("triggered");
        });

    }

    return {
        link:link,
        scope: {
            active: "&elementIsActive"
        }
    }

})
```

I am having trouble getting `$watch` to work. `"triggered"` is output once only on loading, and then it appears to stop `$watch`ing, despite the fact that the output of the function is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to watch over an attribute in scope, easily do this:

```
scope.$watch('active', function (){
```

And as you are already calling the function in `element-is-active="elementIsActive(key)"`, you can just get its return value as a normal variable in your scope:

```
return {
    link:link,
    scope: {
        active: "=elementIsActive"
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/c8cprrmhF5zkzqGFbXbR?p=preview).